# SQL Statement issue with the Postgresql Support in CakePHP 2.4.7 and TreeBehavior

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, tree, cakephp-2.4.7

I run a CakePHP 2.4.7 application, using PostgreSQL as Database.

It seems that CakePHP or the `PGSQL DBO source` don't correctly format the SQL queries for Postgre when contain `Group By` or `Order BY`.

I gotten this error trying to save a "simple" model acting as Tree via TreeBehavior. 
It's from a POST / create action.

Database Thrown Error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "Emplacement.reference" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: ...RE 1 = 1 AND "Emplacement"."id" <> 126 ORDER BY "reference... ^
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT MAX("Emplacement"."rght") AS "rght" 
FROM "mpdefault"."emplacements" AS "Emplacement" 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND "Emplacement"."id" <> 126 ORDER BY "reference" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Stack Trace:

```
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 458 → PDOStatement->execute(array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 424 → DboSource->_execute(string, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 665 → DboSource->execute(string, array, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 1077 → DboSource->fetchAll(string, boolean)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 2903 → DboSource->read(Emplacement, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 2875 → Model->_readDataSource(string, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/TreeBehavior.php line 1013 → Model->find(string, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/TreeBehavior.php line 932 → TreeBehavior->_getMax(Emplacement, string, string, integer, boolean)
CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/TreeBehavior.php line 96 → TreeBehavior->_setParent(Emplacement, string, boolean)
[internal function] → TreeBehavior->afterSave(Emplacement, boolean, array)
CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php line 132 → call_user_func_array(array, array)
[internal function] → ObjectCollection->trigger(CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php line 247 → call_user_func(array, CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 1861 → CakeEventManager->dispatch(CakeEvent)
APP/Controller/EmplacementsController.php line 87 → Model->save(array)
[internal function] → EmplacementsController->admin_add()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(EmplacementsController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 185 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 160 → Dispatcher->_invoke(EmplacementsController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Since the query is written in the Core Framework that I don't know, I request your help to understand and resolve this issue.

Do you think that upgrading my version to cakephp-2.6 could be help ?

Postgre SQL (regular SQL specifications) reject this request (made by cake in my case):

```
SELECT MAX("Emplacement"."rght") AS "rght"
FROM "mpdefault"."emplacements" AS "Emplacement" 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND "Emplacement"."id" = 126 
ORDER BY "reference" ASC LIMIT 1
```

but it seems that mySQL is Okay with that.

PostgreSQL accepted queries could be :

```
SELECT MAX("Emplacement"."rght") AS "rght"
FROM "mpdefault"."emplacements" AS "Emplacement" 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND "Emplacement"."id" = 126
```

or

```
SELECT MAX("Emplacement"."rght") AS "rght"
FROM "mpdefault"."emplacements" AS "Emplacement" 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND "Emplacement"."id" = 126 
group by "reference"
ORDER BY "reference" ASC LIMIT 1
```

But these queries are non-sense.

Why CakePHP add a "ORDER BY" or "ORDER BY" clause on a `MAX()` SELECT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the cause was that I have a property Emplacement::$order defined as "reference ASC", then cakePHP add `ORDER BY reference ASC` after each SQL query, causing the throw of the previous error.

I rceated a new issue on CakePHP github account for this issue : https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5155